# How to add custom handling to relationships (join tables) in SaveChanges in DbContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a custom DbContext that I am using to log any changes (inserts, updates, deletes) made through EF to the database.  It works by overriding the `SaveChanges` method on `DbContext`.  It works more or less like this:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (DbEntityEntry entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
       Log(entry);
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

This works reasonably well for changes to entities, for instance, a Client or an Employee.  However, I am having a hard time figuring out how to log changes to relationships between entities.  For instance, there is a ClientEmployee join table that has a ClientId and an EmployeeId.  EF correctly interprets this relationship and put a `virtual ICollection` of the other table on each table.  How can I find which relationships got added and removed during `SaveChanges()`?  I need to be able to log them (whether they were added or deleted) even when the only difference is that a row was created or deleted in the join table.

The temporary solution I have been using is to make my join tables into entities by adding a primary key and creating the rows manually in code, but this is cumbersome and just doesn't feel right.  In the example above, Employees would have a `virtual ICollection<ClientEmployee>` and each `ClientEmployee` entity would have a single `Client` and a single `Employee`.  This gets the job done, but it increases developer overhead and potential for error among all the developers who have to learn and follow this unorthodox pattern.

Is there any way I can get a preview of the changes to relationships (each individual inserted or deleted row of the join table, if possible) even though the changes are not, strictly speaking, to entities?

Comment: Have you looked at http://jmdority.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/using-entity-framework-4-1-dbcontext-change-tracking-for-audit-logging/  and http://www.softcodearticle.com/2013/07/entity-framework-auditing-implementation/

Comment: I hadn't seen those articles, but they both seem to be doing basically the same thing I am.  The ChangeTracker exposes the entities that are being inserted, updated or deleted, and I can log those just fine.  However, I can't figure out how to get the join table records out of the change tracker.  For instance, if I am affiliating one employee with three clients, all 4 of those entities show up as unchanged because none of the information on those rows is changed.  I am, however, adding 4 rows to the join table linking them together.  These are the rows I need to log/audit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. The key is to convert the `DbContext` into its underlying `ObjectContext`. For each `Added` entity, you will be logging only added related entities. For each `Modified` entity, you will need to log both deleted and added related entities.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (DbEntityEntry entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
       Log(entry);

       switch(entry.State)
       {
          case EntityState.Added:
             Log(GetRelatedEntityKeys(this, entry, EntityState.Added));
             break;

          case EntityState.Modified:
             Log(GetRelatedEntityKeys(this, entry, EntityState.Added));
             Log(GetRelatedEntityKeys(this, entry, EntityState.Deleted));
             break;
       }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

The code for inspecting the relationships is:

```
private static IList<EntityKey> GetRelatedEntityKeys(DbContext context, DbEntityEntry entry, EntityState entityState)
{
    ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;

    ObjectStateManager objectStateManager = objectContext.ObjectStateManager;

    ObjectStateEntry pivotEntityStateEntry;

    if (!objectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(entry.Entity, out pivotEntityStateEntry))
    {
        return null;
    }

    EntityKey pivotEntityKey = pivotEntityStateEntry.EntityKey;

    if (entityState == EntityState.Deleted)
    {
        return objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Deleted)
            .Where(e => e.IsRelationship && ((EntityKey)e.OriginalValues[0] == pivotEntityKey || (EntityKey)e.OriginalValues[1] == pivotEntityKey))
            .Select(e => (EntityKey)e.OriginalValues[0] == pivotEntityKey ? (EntityKey)e.OriginalValues[1] : (EntityKey)e.OriginalValues[0])
            .ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
            .Where(e => e.IsRelationship && ((EntityKey)e.CurrentValues[0] == pivotEntityKey || (EntityKey)e.CurrentValues[1] == pivotEntityKey))
            .Select(e => (EntityKey)e.CurrentValues[0] == pivotEntityKey ? (EntityKey)e.CurrentValues[1] : (EntityKey)e.CurrentValues[0])
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

If you need the `DbEntityEntry` instead of the `EntityKey`, you can look up the entities this way:

```
private static DbEntityEntry GetRelatedEntityByKey(DbContext context, EntityKey relatedEntityKey)
{
    ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;

    object relatedEntity;
    if (objectContext.TryGetObjectByKey(relatedEntityKey, out relatedEntity))
    {
        return context.Entry(relatedEntity);
    }

    return null;
}
```

You will need to add logging capability for the list of related entities, but it appears that you have the logging portion of the code in hand.